# How to use Selenium to install Firefox browser add-on?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I would like to use Selenium to install an add-on to my Firefox browser. Specifically, I have an add-on called "nopecha" that I would like to install.

Could you kindly guide me on how to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

To add NopeCHA to Firefox using Selenium, you can use the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
driver.install_addon("nopecha.xpi")
```

*Make sure to replace `nopecha.xpi` with the actual file path of the NopeCHA extension on your system.*

However, there is no need to install this specific add-on manually using Selenium, since an official [NopeCHA Python library](https://github.com/NopeCHALLC/nopecha-python) is available.